# Using JQuery AJAX to fill a table in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a populated dropdown list in my view and when i choose one date from the list I want to fill another table with data from the database.

I created a controller method called description that takes too parameters as seen below, which returns the data that I need in JSON format

When I manualy enter the url I get the correct json response but when I try to pass the url using Ajax it does not work.

My Controller Code

```
public function description($car,$date)

{

    $description = DB::table("histories")
        ->where('crn',$car)
        ->where("date",$date)
        ->get();
    return json_encode($description);

}
```

My Route

```
Route::get('admin/cars/history/{car}/{date}','CarController@description');
```

My view

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="{{url('admin')}}">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{url('admin/cars')}}">Car</a></li>
        <li class="active">{{$car->crn}}</li>
    </ol>

    <div class="box box-success">
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-heading"><h3>Car Details</h3></div>
            <div class="box-header with-border">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="owner">Owner</label>
                    <p>{{$car->customer->name}}</p></div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="manufacturer">Manufacturer</label>
                    <p>{{$car->manufacturer}}</p></div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="model">Model</label>
                    <p>{{$car->model}}</p></div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="address">Last Visit</label>
                    <p>{{$lastservice->created_at->toFormattedDateString()}}</p></div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Select Date to view history records</label>
                    <select name="date" class="form-control" style="width:250px">
                        <option value="">--- Select Date ---</option>
                        @foreach ($history as $date => $value)
                            <option value="{{ $date }}">{{ $value }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>

                    <a href="{{url('admin/cars/')}}" class="btn btn-default">Back</a></div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

My JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var results = $('#results');
        $('select[name="date"]').on('change', function() {
            var $date = $('option:selected').text();

            $.ajax({

                url: 'admin/cars/history/HNH419/'+$date,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",

                success:function(response){
                    alert(response);
                }})
        })
    });
</script>
```

An example of my Interface
[image]

Comment: Are you testing this in localhost or something?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Is it getting to the controller via Ajax just not returning anything?

Comment: I am testing in localhost.I am not getting any errors, actually nothing happens when I choose a date from the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, It worked when I added “localhost” in front of my ajax `url`.

Because there is no url like `“admin/cars/history/HNH419/…”` , actually there is something like `“localhost/admin/cars/history/HNH419/….”`

Tip: you have to use full address in address bar when you try it manually.

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: host_url+'forum/question/add',
// code continues
```

In my case, `host_url = “localhost:8000”`

Comment: Thank you. It was in fact an issue with the url. I replaced the url with `url: "{{$car->crn}}" +"/" + $date,` and I am getting the correct json response